# Getting black screenshot for ie driver server

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I have recently upgraded selenium version to 3.141.59
IEdriver 3.14
When I trigger the scripts to execute under Jenkins remote machine, getting black screenshot and timeout exception occurred as I wait for next element.
Could you please explain possible solutions to me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.

Comment: Please post some code to help others to answer your query.